# Reading an image with dd from a hard disk connected to a raid controller does not make it over 4GB

Tags: dd, raid

I am trying to create an image of a HDD connected to a Promise Fastrack TX2300.
I am trying to do this with the live Linux 'grml'.

The hardware on which this is taking place is long past its best days: Pentium4@2.8GHz, 1GB Ram, mainly running Windows XP.

The PC is installed in an industrial machine that I would not like to disassemble to physically access the HDDs. (never touch a running system)

- So I booted grml from the USB stick and loaded the image in Ram (boot parameter 'toram').
- Manually assigned the network interface IP 10.1.0.1.
- On a laptop connected directly to the network interface with an ethernet cable, start netcat in listening mode `nc -l 7777 > hdd_raw.img`.
- On the PC with the HDD to be backed up: `dd if=/dev/dm-0 bs=64K | nc 10.1.0.2 7777`.

But each time dd only reads 4.194.304KB and then quits (without an error message and with returncode 0) so I would rule out dd as the source of the error.

The HDD has a capacity of 160GB.

- Even if I read `/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/dm-0`: 4GB -> stop.
- Also when I change the block size. i tried *512*, *1K*, *512K*, *8M*.

The installed RAID controller is a *Promise Fastrack TX 2300*, and the loaded kernel module is `sata_promise`.

`uname -a` says:

```
Linux grml 6.0.0-4-686 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.8-1 (2022-11-11) i686 GNU/Linux
```

The output of `dmesg`: https://dpaste.org/93bE3/raw

How do I get the rest of the data from *sda*/*dm-0*?

Comment: What file system is the disk which you are attempting to save "hdd_raw.img" currently using?  I am not sure why there would be a problem reading larger amounts of data from the raid controller, but there are certainly file systems that cannot handle single files larger then 4gb

Comment: Oh! I hadn't thought of that at all. But of course! FAT32 only likes 4GB! Thank you! Can you post this as an answer so that I can mark it as solved? That way the kudos go to you ;)

Comment: Instead of `dd if=/dev/dm-0 bs=64K | nc 10.1.0.2 7777`, consider using the much faster (and simpler) `nc 10.1.0.2 7777 </dev/dm-0`

Comment: Thanks @roaima. Since the network interface can only handle 10MBit, I didn't notice the speed loss. But good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GracefulRestart wrote, it was simply due to the incorrectly chosen file system. FAT32 can only handle files up to 4GB.
Switching to NTFS, ext4 or extFAT will remedy this.